# Vector Calculus curl, divergence and gradient identity

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

Here is the identity I need to prove:

$\vec\nabla\cdot(\vec\nabla f\times (\vec r f)) = 0$, where $f$ is a smooth scalar field and $\vec r$ is the position vector.

Some tips would be brilliant!

Comment: Have you tried calculating it using the definitions? Since $f$ is smooth, the mixed derivative theorem should allow you to cancel terms.